# Graph function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, graph

I have such a data type :

```
data Node a = Node
    { label :: a,
        adjacent :: [(a,Int)] } deriving Show
```

Example : `( Node 'a' [ ( 'b' , 3 ) , ( 'c' ,2 ) ] )` 
I want to get the label from this structure, I wrote this function (and several other combinations which I thought might work) :

```
giveLabel Node a [(c,b)] = a;
```

But I keep getting errors. Can you tell me how should I change my function? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
giveLabel (Node a [(c,b)]) = a
```

Is the syntax you want - defining functions uses the same rules of precedence as calling them, and according to those rules, you defined a function `giveLabel` with three arguments (`Node`, `a`, and `[c,b]`); and that was illegal because in that context `Node` was missing arguments.

Even that probably isn't what you want - the pattern [(c,b)] only matches lists with exactly one item in. Since you don't care about the list of neighbours you can write:

```
giveLabel (Node a xs) = a
```

...where `xs` will bind to the whole list of neighbours; but actually since you don't even care about that, you can write:

```
giveLabel (Node a _) = a
```

...where `_` is a useful way of pattern matching against a parameter you aren't going to use.

Comment: Main> giveLabel ( Node 'a' [ ( 'b' , 3 ) , ( 'c' ,2 ) ] ) 

Program error: pattern match failure: giveLabel (Node 'a' [('b',3),('c',2)])

Comment: Right. The example I gave you does force the list to be only one item long. Will edit my answer to explain.